# ng-include in angular 1.2 not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zurb-foundation, angularjs-ng-include

I can't make the ng-include directive work. I've watched and tried several solutions from stackoverflow but none of them seems to be working. Am I missing something ? Angular works everywhere in the document, except for this. The div is not emebeded in anything.

I am using the foundation framework. Is it possible that it causes the problem ?

Here is the code in my index.html:

```
  <div ng-include="'partials/menu.html'"></div>
```

I checked and rechecked, I DO have a "partials" folder containing a "menu.html" file...

I have also tried:

```
  <div ng-include src="'partials/menu.html'"></div>
```

and

```
  <div ng-include="'/partials/menu.html'"></div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help you could give me !

Comment: Can you check your console / developer tools for any error messages?

Comment: OK, I get it. It seems you cannot do http requests in chrome on a local file. The console showed an error about that. I tried opening the file in firefox and it worked. I assume this error will not occure once the file is uploaded on a server.

P.S: Sorry I have to put this answer in a comment, but because of my rate I cannot answer my own question right now

Answer (score 2):

You have the correct code here:

```
<div ng-include=" 'partials/menu.html' "></div>
```

so it's most likely a path issue. If your partials folder is not inside the same folder as the html file you're calling the partial into, you might need something like `'../partials/menu.html'`. You might try creating a simple 'hello world' like partials/test.html with no angular functionality and use that to find the correct path and get your ng-include working.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer. I actually figured out what the problem was.  It seems you cannot do http requests in chrome on a local file. The console showed an error about that. I tried opening the file in firefox and it worked. I assume this error will not occure once the file is uploaded on a server.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the use of single and double quotation, you only need one of them, like this:

```
<div ng-include="partials/menu.html"></div>
```

This works as well

```
<div ng-include='partials/menu.html'></div>
```